# Placing a key variable in internal flash Memory

Tags: arm, keil, stm32l

I am trying to place a variable named *secret_key* at location `0x08002000` in STM32Nucleo-board which has STM32L476RG on board with 1MB flash.

**Question 1:** Why am i unable to place code in custom ROM (`SECRET_IROM1` )section?
**Question 2:** What is the mistake i am doing?

I am still newbie to Linker topic.

I am able to do it(still do not undestnad, why other RO section also follows my new address of secret_key variable) if i define the address which is in the default section for `RO` in the scatter file. If i create a new section, mapping is not happening. I can see the address assigned as expected but the value of the *secret_key* is not visible at that location.

below image shows what happens when i declare the address out of range from the default section.

Code section where variable is declared:

```
unsigned long long int array4[6]={0};
unsigned long long int array[6]={12};

unsigned long long int arra2[4] = {0x1111111111111111,0x2222222222222222,0x3333333333333333,0x4444444444444444};
const long secret_key[3] __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x8001800"))) = {0xABABABAB,0xCDCDCDCD, 0xEFEFEFEF};
extern int addsum(int, int);

int main()
       {
    long long int array3[100] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    array[1] = arra2[1] - array[0]+array3[1]*2+array3[2]*2+addsum(array[1],array[2])+array4[2]+(int)secret_key[0];
    while(1);
}
```

Memory map below:
[image]

Scatter file contents below:

```
; *************************************************************
; *** Scatter-Loading Description File generated by uVision ***
; *************************************************************

LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00100000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00002000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
  }

  SECRET_IROM1 0x08002000 0x00000030  {  ; load address = execution address
  *(.ARM.__at_0x8001800) ; secret key
  }

  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00000100  {  ; RW data
   project2.o (+RW)
   }

  RW_IRAM2 0x20000100 0x00000100  {  ; RW data
   project2.o (+ZI)
   }

  RW_IRAM3 0x20000200 0x00000300  {  ; RW data
   project.o (+ZI)   
  }

  RW_IRAM4 0x20000500 0x00000200  {  ; RW data
   project.o (+RW)   
  }

  RW_IRAM5 0x20000700 0x00001000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW,+ZI)   
  }
}
```

**Second case: where it doesn't work**

Code here:

```
unsigned long long int array4[6]={0};
unsigned long long int array[6]={12};

unsigned long long int arra2[4] = {0x1111111111111111,0x2222222222222222,0x3333333333333333,0x4444444444444444};
const long secret_key[3] __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x8002100"))) = {0xABABABAB,0xCDCDCDCD, 0xEFEFEFEF};
extern int addsum(int, int);

int main()
       {
    long long int array3[100] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    array[1] = arra2[1] - array[0]+array3[1]*2+array3[2]*2+addsum(array[1],array[2])+array4[2]+(int)secret_key[0];
    while(1);
}
```

associated scatter file here:

```
; *************************************************************
; *** Scatter-Loading Description File generated by uVision ***
; *************************************************************

LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00100000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00001800  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
  }

  SECRET_IROM1 0x08002100 0x00000030  {  ; load address = execution address
  *(.ARM.__at_0x8002100) ; secret key
  }

  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00000100  {  ; RW data
   project2.o (+RW)
   }

  RW_IRAM2 0x20000100 0x00000100  {  ; RW data
   project2.o (+ZI)
   }

  RW_IRAM3 0x20000200 0x00000300  {  ; RW data
   project.o (+ZI)   
  }

  RW_IRAM4 0x20000500 0x00000200  {  ; RW data
   project.o (+RW)   
  }

  RW_IRAM5 0x20000700 0x00001000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW,+ZI)   
  }
}
```

memory map below:
[image]

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Results of suggestion fron Jeroen3

[image]
[image]

I am **expecting** the values loaded into the variable secret_key to be visible in the flash memory region, but it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**secretkey.c:**

```
const long secret_key[3] __attribute__((used)) = {0xABABABAB,0xCDCDCDCD, 0xEFEFEFEF};
```

`__attribute__((used))` to prevent it from being removed if it isn't used anywhere.

**secretkey.h:**

```
extern const long secret_key[3];
```

**scatterfile.sct:**
Make a region and a C file, then add the RO (read only) part of that C file to the region. Nothing else.

```
; *************************************************************
; *** Scatter-Loading Description File generated by uVision ***
; *************************************************************

LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00002000 {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00002000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
  }

  RW_IRAM1...
}

LR_SECRET_IROM1 0x08002000 0x00000030  {                         
  SECRET_IROM1 0x08002000 0x00000030  {
    secretkey.o (+RO)
  }
}
```

You now have two **load regions** (`lr_`), these blocks of memory (regions) are programmed into flash by the programmer. `LR_IROM1` and `LR_SECRET_IROM1`.
Inside the *load regions* are *execution regions*. This is where the code references the objects from. `ER_IROM1`, `RW_IRAM1` and `SECRET_IROM1`.

Most often the addresses of the load and execution region are identical.
But you can have a *load region* for flash, and an *execution region* for sram.
For example with pre-initialized variables. This means the linker then must insert the *scatter loading* algorithm. This copies the data from the flash location where the data is programmed in flash, to the intended usable location in sram. (i.e. where the code thinks the variables are)

This algorithm is called from the *startup.s* file, and it makes the jump to `int main(void)`, for Keil this algorithm is started by calling `__main` in `startup.s`.

But when the execution region already equals the load region, no copying is required. Such as with the actual code, and your now with constant.

*In my earlier version (and the part in your question), the constant was put inside an execution region, meaning it was programmed using `.ANY (+RO)` and then copied to the intended location. Except the code can't write to flash, thus nothing would be changed there.*

See also, [ARM® Compiler armlink User Guide: 8.2 Syntax of a scatter file](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0493e/Chdbjdii.html)
I'd also recommend looking at the memory `.map` file the linker outputs. You can use it to verify how your image is put together. I made a small [tool](https://github.com/Jeroen6/MapViewer) for this.
The tickbox is in `target settings -> listing -> linker listing`.

---

Your RAM regions are a bit strange. I do not think there is an advantage in using multiple 256 sized regions.

Instead, you could use all SRAM regions:
- 96 kByte at 0x20000000
- 32 kByte at 0x10000000

Comment: I will try this. Thanks for the guidance. Please give a day time.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution. i am unable to see the values in the location still. all i see is 0xFF only. can you please comment on here i am going wrong?

Comment: @Umar Are you sure your project is using the custom scatterfile and not the target dialog?

Comment: Yes. Because the address assigned to the variable is 0x8003000 as mentioned in scatter file.

Comment: @Umar I've been wrong. see my edit. These things you generally setup once per project and then forget about.

Comment: Great. Thank you. one more request! I did not clearly understand the load regions concept still. Is there a reason why i should have two load region? how to understand more about it? can you guide me please?

Comment: @Umar I have tried to make the text better. You can also read the [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0493e/Chdbjdii.html), use the navigator on the left, or click on pdf version.